# Describing measurable functions for a 0-1 measure space.

Tags: measure-theory

This question is inspired by problem 1.6 in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis".

There is an uncountable set $X$, and $R$ is the collection of all subsets $E$ of $X$ s.t. either $E$ or $E^C$ is at most countable. I know how to show that $R$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is a measure on $R$ if $\mu(E)=0$ for $E$ that is most countable and $\mu(E)=1$ if $E^C$ is at most countable.

I'm stuck with describing measurable functions. My guess is that all measurable functions are constants on $X\backslash E$ for some at most countable $E$. Namely I can show that there exists at most one element $a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f^{-1}(a)$ is uncountable. But what if for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ $f^{-1}(a)$ is at most countable? Can $f$ still be measurable? My intuition tells me it can't, but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Every set of the form $[z,z+1]$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So the preimage $f^{-1}[z,z+1]$ is measurable too. Every measurable subset of $X$ ha measure $0$ or $1$. If all these sets have measure zero, so does $X$ by countable additivity. So $\mu (f^{-1}[z,z+1])=1$ for some $z$. Divide this set $[z,z+1]$ in two closed intervals of equal length $[z,z+1/2]$ and $[z+1/2,z+1]$. Again, the preimage of one of these intervals must have measure $1$, divide this agian and continue this way. So you get a sequence of nested closed intervals with diameter going to zero. So the intersection contains a single point $r$ and $\mu (f^{-1}\{r\})=1$, since the intersection of countably many measurable sets of measure $1$ in a probability space has again measure $1$. So $f(x)=r$ for all but countably many $x$.

Comment: "Every set of the form $[z,z+1]$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So the preimage $f^{-1}[z,z+1]$ is measurable too." I thought that $f^{-1}([z,z+1])$ being measurable followed from the fact that $[z,z+1]$ is closed and preimages of open and closed sets under measurable functions are measurable. Is that wrong?

Comment: @user193319 It's not wrong.